# Apache-ignite cluster taking long to start

Tags: windows, ignite

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvVyf.png]

Configured ignite cluster using 3 windows machines, after starting server from command line
in windows machine .Its taking long time around 1 hour to start all 3 nodes .

i have tried changing -J-Xmx value like 3000m, 5000m ..etc

ex:(IgnitePersistenceApp.exe  -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx3000m -J-XX:+UseParNewGC -J-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -J-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=548m -springConfigUrl="server-config.xml" --console)

Here is my setup details-----
node 1 - os : windows 10
ram 15gb

node 2 - os : windows 10
ram 12gb

node 3 - os : windows 10
ram 12gb

Answer (score 0):

What disks do you happen to use on the nodes? If it is HDD, restoring partition state may take a lot of time. Better use SSD with Apache Ignite.

Otherwise, please enable verbose mode (`ignite.bat -v` or `-DIGNITE_QUIET=false`) and share the complete log.

Comment: thanks for reply ,  i'm using HDD not SSD , im a new bie, how to  make this option as false for DIGNITE_QUITE

Comment: just add -v option to ignite.bat. On HDD you may expect nodes taking a long time to start after restart with persistence.

Comment: thank u for your response, in code i reduced the timeout seconds (failuredetection) in TCPspidiscovery property ,i started server in node 1 and then after node got started and then i started server in node 2 after successfully startup of server then started server in node 3 ..so after changes and starting all 3 servers GRACEFULLY every node is taking only two minutes before it was taking around 1 hour ..

Comment: There may be issue with discovery under Windows where it tries all ports one by one. Unfortunately I don't have Windows box so I can't address the issue.